# Chrome form.submit not going to right URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome

I have a form,

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="MyPage" id="myForm" style="display:inline;"> </form>
```

which I am submitting with Javascript.

```
function performFunction() {
    $('#myForm:first').submit();
}
```

In IE and FF this will go the right post action in my asp.net app; so mySite.com/MyPage. In Chrome however it appears to just be going to mySite.com. Looking into the network tab I can see the request to the server is indeed just mySite.com. Stranger yet is if I use the above JS code in the DevTools console it will submit correctly, even when breakpointed on that exact point.

I was looking into if form attributes were getting change directly after the submit as I was reading chrome has a problem with that. That however doesn't seem to be the case.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Try setting the `action` to `/MyPage` so that it's explicit that the URL should be relative to the root. Also, the `:first` selector is redundant since you are selecting by `id` which has to be unique within the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
action="MyPage"
```

to

```
action="/MyPage"
```

If this solution doesn't work, try:

```
function performFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var myForm = $('#myForm');
        myForm.action = '/MyPage';

        form.submit();
    }, 0);
};
```

Read more about this issue here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104205